# Javascript regex replace to transform text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace `<h[num] id="....">Header</h[num]>` with `h[num]. Header`

This is what I have tried, but I cannot get it to work:

`html.replace('/<h(\d+).*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/h.*?>/', "h$1. $2");`

Comment: All is lost [the pony he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)!

Comment: @Jongware - If I have confused you too much I apologise. Let me make it simpler for you. Imagine html doesn't exist for a minute. All I am trying to do trying to do is parse the following `<h[num] id="....">Header</h[num]>` into `h[num]. Header`.

Comment: You must not do it with regex, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1243636

Comment: @akaRem - If I have confused you too much I apologise. Let me make it simpler for you. Imagine html doesn't exist for a minute. All I am trying to do trying to do is parse the following `<h[num] id="....">Header</h[num]>` into `h[num]. Header`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it can.

Check the example in http://jsfiddle.net/cLHk3/

```
function replaceHTML(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5');
    Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element){
        var text = element.tagName+'. Header';     
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(text),element);
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('br'),element);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was the following:

```
var html = <h1 id="....">Header</h1>
var re = /^<h(\d+)[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*)<\/h(\d+)>$/;

html.replace(re, "h$1. $2");
```